# Compare the two textbox values in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am comparing the two textbox values.

I am fetching the changes word from second textbox but work only some sentence see below output fine

[image: output perfect]

The problem shows up when I write another sentence in the second text box, for example: "hello are you made"

[image: output not perfect]

**WebForm1.aspx**

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ftextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="stextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <br /><br /> 
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Compare" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack)
   {
       Label2.Text = "";
       Label1.Text = "";
   }

   //change word
   var result = stextbox.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Except(ftextbox.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' })).ToArray();
   int count = result.Length;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       Label1.Text += result[i].ToString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }

   Label2.Text = "Old Text is:";
   Label1.Text = "Chnage Text is:" + Label1.Text;

   //old Words
   string[] tempArr1 = ftextbox.Text.Split(' ');
   string[] tempArr2 = stextbox.Text.Split(' ');
   int counter = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < tempArr1.Length; i++)
   {
       if (tempArr1[i] != tempArr2[i])
       {
           Label2.Text = Label2.Text + tempArr1[i] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

           counter++;
       }
   }
}
```

First image shows perfect output but second is not.

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.6927&rep=rep1&type=pdf, is a good start to string comparaison. Based on your serie of question are you trying to implement some kind of Diff like when you compare codes in a code editor? Is the implementation important or do you want the minial via 3rd party lib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all unique words in an input when you use `Split()` to cut them into words and then use `Distinct()` to only get unique words.

You can now use these two `IEnumerable<string>` to compare them with `Except()` to get the strings that are different.

**CompareString Function:**

```cs
public List<string> CompareStrings(string s1, string s2) {
    // Create IEnumerable<string> of each word in the given string
    IEnumerable<string> set1 = s1.Split(' ').Distinct();
    IEnumerable<string> set2 = s2.Split(' ').Distinct();
    
    // Compare and return the Difference
    return set1.Except(set2).ToList();
}
```

We can now call this function twice to detect the changes in the `ftextbox` compared to the `stextbox` and the changes in the `stextbox` comapred to the `ftextbox`

**Example:**

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string oldtText = string.Empty;

    // Get words that are different in ftextbox compared to stextbox
    foreach (string change in CompareStrings(ftextbox.Text, stextbox.Text)) {
        oldText += " " + change;
    }

    Label2.Text = "Old Text is:" + oldText;
   
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string newText = string.Empty;

    // Get words that are different in stextbox compared to ftextbox
    foreach (string change in CompareStrings(stextbox.Text, ftextbox.Text)) {
        newText += " " + change;
    }

     Label1.Text = "Change Text is:" + newText;
}
```

Comment: why here ```you``` is distinct keyword and other are not distinct keyword because you is a only one time can you please explain https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ6iY.png

Comment: see this debugger why actual output and debugger are different https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8DOc.png

Comment: Ah thats what the first line does is put all unique strings into a IEnuemrable and in the return you are only sending the ones that are different

Comment: if I not use distict keyword then output is fine why?

Comment: That is because right now you don't enter a word twice. If you do tough than it will only work correctly with the `.Distinct()` added.